# How to use Telegram API in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, telegram

I would like to use Telegram API for Windows Phone 8.  Though unlike other platforms, Telegram doesn't provide source code for Windows Phone.  This is unfortunate because it creates a lot of problems for those who want to use it.  From my research people mention using **REST** Service to accomplish that.  Though no one showed any exact solution for how to accomplish it.  I also read about using **RPC** calls to accomplish it.  I don't know how to do that and I would greatly appreciate someone who could explain step by step to how to implement Telegram in ones app.  Big Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to see source code of an app using the Telegram API you should take a look at `github`.

There are a lot of apps there using this API:

**API, Protocol documentation**

Documentation for Telegram API is available here: http://core.telegram.org/api

Documentation for MTproto protocol is available here: http://core.telegram.org/mtproto

Take a look at this one https://telegram.org/apps#telegram-for-wp

You can browser their source code there downloading the zip. Unfortunatelly Stackoverflow does not permit we post a step by step walkthrough of using an API.

Comment: if i need step by step how to use telegram api using .net simple api calls, and the last link is broken

Comment: @KhalidOmar Thank's for the heads up. I fixed with a link to another project hosted by them (Telegram).

Comment: thank you i need some document on how to call telegram rest api if you have

Comment: @KhalidOmar Sorry. I don't have this knowledge.

Comment: i'think tell know few may have :) the api too complecated Thank you